# Unexpected End of Input (JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an `unexpected end of input` for, inside my HTML+CSS+Javascript program,

```
window.setInterval(alert("pls work"), 60000);
```

I'm not sure how to fix this; most of the other `unexpected end of input`'s I've seen others have errors with seem to have syntax errors, but I think there isn't any syntax error here. I have two other `setInterval()`'s inside my program.

Comment: Not sure what kind of help you expect with the information given. You can always eliminate code around the problem and see if the error goes away then re-introduce code until it breaks again.

Comment: Is there any syntax error you see? Actually, now that I've removed it, it seems to be that the error pops up at the line right before the `</script>` tag. Does this mean there is an error earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval is meant to take first argument as a function:

```
window.setInterval(function() { 
     alert("pls work") 
}, 60000);
```

Comment: That's right, `alert('pls work')` is a function **call**, not a function. Easy to get these mixed up when you're starting out, but it comes with practice.